# Lucene vs. Azure Search

Tags: lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I am a newbie to search engines and information retrieval. Can someone explain how different is Lucene search engine compared to Azure Search.

I read the Azure Search documents and see that Azure Search supports Lucene queries as well, so is Azure Search built on top of Lucene or inherits certain features of it?

There is no proper documentation as such, can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Azure Search is not built on top of Apache Lucene as such, but it does support Lucene Query syntax.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search

Answer (score 13):

According to this Microsoft page the full text search is built on Lucene.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-azure-search
"The full text search engine in Azure Search is built on Apache Lucene, an industry standard in information retrieval."